# Relativistic Addition of Orthogonal Velocities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Stuck on a homework question and unsure how to approach orthogonal addition. Any help would be appreciated.

In a given inertial frame, two particles are shot out simultaneously from a given point,
with equal speed v, in orthogonal directions.
Using a conventional approach to solving relative velocity problems, and without using
4-vectors, show that the speed of each particle relative to the other is given by:

> $$v_R = v\left(2- \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^{2}\right)^{1/2}$$

Derive the same result using 4-velocity vectors.

What I tried:

Taken inertial frame S. Considering particles emitted in x and y directions.
Let S' be the frame of the particle going in y direction where
$x=0$,
$y=vt$
$$x'= -vt$$
$$y' = vt$$

Inverse lorentz transformation from S' to S
$$t=(t' + vx/c^2) $$
with $x=0$ gives
$$t=t'$$

Substitute into $x'$ and $y'$

$$x' = -^2vt'$$

$$y' = vt'$$

Not sure where I would go for here or if this is the right approach to take :-)

Comment: What are $U$ and $u$ defined as ?  BTW, generally I discourage people from using upper and lower case symbols that look similar as symbols can be resized by formatting and lead to confusion.

Comment: @StephenG sorry that was an capitalization mistake on my part!

Comment: What have you done to answer this question? Please share your thinking and attempts and concepts in your question. Otherwise this is a "do my homework question" which is off-topic on PSE.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkins edited original post with my thoughts so far, not sure where to go from there. Sorry!

Comment: You are using a Lorentz boost in the x-direction. If you want $S'$ to be the frame of the particle moving in the y-direction, then the Lorentz transformation must be a Lorentz boost in the y-direction, not in the x-direction.